# Applescript dynamic convert type in a list

Tags: applescript

I want to convert date each one to a type in a type list such as *{string,integer,text,...}*, like this:

```
set ret to {}
set aStringList to {"abc","123","def","456"}
set typeList to {string,integer,string,integer}
repeat with i from 1 to (count aStringList)
    set theStr to item i of aStringList
    set end of ret to theStr as (item i of typeList)
end repeat
log ret
```

Is it possible to implement?

Comment: If you don't quote the numbers, they are treated as integers (assuming whole numbers) not strings. Also, to see the coerced output, use `return ret` not `log ret` as the latter logs `(*abc, 123, def, 456*)` and `return ret` is `{"abc", 123, "def", 456}` and as you can see the numbers are unquoted and are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use dynamic coercions at runtime, coercions are evaluated at compile time.

You have to do something like that:

```
set ret to {}
set aStringList to {"abc", "123", "def", "456"}
set typeList to {string, integer, string, integer}
repeat with i from 1 to (count aStringList)
    set theStr to item i of aStringList
    set classIndex to item i of typeList
    if classIndex = string then
        set end of ret to theStr as string
    else if classIndex = integer then
        set end of ret to theStr as integer
    end if
end repeat
log ret
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's helpful.